# Rearrange a list according to position association with a new list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
l1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
TableForm@Transpose[PadRight[#, 6] & /@ l1]
assoc = {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 0}}, {{1, 
     1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}, {6, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3,
      2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 5}}};
l2 = ConstantArray[0, {3, 6}];
MapThread[
  Function[{u, v, w}, If[#2 > 0, v[[#1]] = u[[#2]]] & @@@ w], {l1, l2,
    assoc}];
TableForm@Transpose@%
```

The goal is to rearrange the `l1` so according to the `assoc` which works as follows e.g. for `l1[[1]]`:
`l1[[1,1;;2]]` will map to `l2[[1,1;;2]]`, `l1[[1,3;;4]]` will map to `l2[[1,4;;5]]` and the rest of `l2[[1]]` will have zeros. So `assoc[[All,All,1]]` contains the positions is `l2` and `assoc[[All,All,2]]` contains positions in `l1` but if `assoc[[All,All,2]]==0` then the appropriate position in `l2` is left as zero.

The code above works to some point, it throws errors and instead of zeros, the result has `Null` values. What would be a nice and elegant way to do this (i am not necessarily requiring to keep the `assoc` array in the exact form, i am looking for a nice and easy way to rearrange an array according the rules explained above).

The goal is to transform the table that looks like (the values in `l1` with padded zeros):

[image]
into one like this (`l2`):
[image]

Where the rules of what from `l1` should go where in `l2` are give in some fashion by saying some position in `l1` should go to some other position in `l2` (such as e.g. in `assoc`)

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by `l1[[1, 1;;2]] will map to l2[[1, 1;;2]]`? Are you referring to a general functional correspondence, or do you mean that those specific values of `l1` should be replaced with the corresponding values of `l2`? It appears that what you want is `MapAt`. If you clarify the question and give a small example of input and output, you might find more help forthcoming.

Comment: @Shredderroy I tried to update the question. Not sure if it is a bit clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up into two routines, to clarify. We don't need the first elements of the `assoc` tuples when done this way.

```
l1p = PadRight[#, 6] & /@ l1
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0}} *)
```

This takes a row of l1p and a row of assoc

```
set[l1r_, assocr_] := Map[If[# != 0, l1r[[#]], 0] &, assocr[[All, 2]] ]
```

Then `MapThread` this over `l1p` and `assoc`

```
l2 = MapThread[set, {l1p, assoc}]
(* {{1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```

Transposed

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 3 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 3 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: You way works. But is there a more general approach to such a problem that works on an arbitrary level of lists? It is basically a permutation problem but extended in the sense that you fill in the non-filled positions with zeros (or something))

Comment: I'm sure there is, but your problem was really just dealing with a row of `l1` three times. No coupling between the rows. If you were assigning an element in one row based on an element in another row, then it gets more complicated. Maybe you can post a more complex problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) using `Position[assoc, {_, Except@0}]` as the non-zero positions and `Join @@ l1` as the non-zero values:

```
l2 = SparseArray[Position[assoc, {_, Except@0}] -> Join @@ l1];


TeXForm @ Row[MatrixForm /@ Transpose /@ {PadRight[l1, {Automatic, 6}], l2}, Spacer[10]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  2 & 2 & 2 \\
>  3 & 3 & 3 \\
>  4 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 2 \\
>  3 & 2 & 3 \\
>  4 & 3 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

A few additional alternatives:

```
l2b = MapIndexed[# /. x_?Positive :> l1[[#2[[1]], x]] &, assoc[[All, All, -1]]];

l2c = Module[{i = 1, jl = Join @@ l1}, Unitize[assoc[[All, All, -1]]] /. 1 :> jl[[i++]]];

l2d = Module[{i = 1, jl = Join @@ l1}, assoc[[All, All, -1]] /. _?Positive :> jl[[i++]]]

l2 == l2b == l2c == l2d
```

> True