# After execution of simple list manipulation every expression turns dark blue and nothing is defined - how to debug

Tags: list-manipulation, memory, kernel, built-in-symbols, debugging

This question is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214540/rearrange-a-list-according-to-position-association-with-a-new-list/214542#214542) in the sense that it uses the code from there.

What happens is best illustrated in the video [here](https://youtu.be/JBB3M1o1I1U). When I run `(* part 1 *)` everything behaves as expected, the same when i run `(* part 2 *)` but when i run `(* part 3 *)` after a second or two, every expression turns blue and nothing is defined any more, not even intrinsic expressions such as `Transpose`. Also not that the blue that everything turns into is darker than the standard blue of undefined expression. (this is experienced on Linux with Mathematica 12.0)

How can I even begin determining what happened and why it behaves the way it does? Note that if I use the code exactly from the post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214540/rearrange-a-list-according-to-position-association-with-a-new-list/214542#214542) as mentioned above, the problem does not appear.

The text files that are being used in the code above can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJ0ChmWHxFV8RRVlWqDFS7bxbsPLS8WL/view?usp=sharing). The offending notebook file can be directly downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j-h1FJm2Ef3Ao3zo6BIXsEz6sPbGsBb2/view?usp=sharing).

The related code rewritten is this:

```
(* part 1 *)
runs = {9, 11, 12, 13, 14};
data = Import[
     StringJoin["KBr-run", ToString@#, ".txt"], 
     "Table"] & /@ runs;
values = data[[#]][[500 ;;, 2]] & /@ Range[Length@runs];
peaks = MapThread[
   Function[{u, v}, 
    FindPeaks[u, 0, Automatic, v, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1]], {values, {1300, 500, 500, 500, 
     500}}];
peakangles = 
  MapThread[
   Function[{u, v}, u[[#]] & /@ v], {data, 
    Floor@peaks[[All, All, 1]] + 499}];
peakangles2 = 
  PadRight[#, Max@(Length /@ peakangles), {{0, 0}}] & /@ peakangles;
zero = {{1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 
    3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 
    6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10,
     0}};
(* part 2 *)
orglist[l1r_, assocr_] := Map[If[# != 0, l1r[[#]], 0] &, assocr];
(* part 3 *)
l2 = MapThread[orglist, {peakangles2[[2 ;;]], zero}]
```

Comment: The dark blue means the kernel has crashed. Likely, part 3 is generating an intermediate that doesn't fit into memory. That said, the code works fine on my machine. How much memory is available on the system you're doing this on?

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce on my machine. Looks like it's the Suggestions Bar that's crashing, consider disabling it in Preferences.

Comment: @eyorble it is 8GB machine and during execution, i can now see that after executing the last line, one of the kernels crashes (After opening the notebook, i have two processes called `Mathematica` and two `WolframKernel`). After executing the last line, one of the kernels crashes as well as some process called `xml.exe`.

Comment: @eyorble Disabling the Suggestion Bar does indeed avoid the crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/75284#75284)

Comment: Anyways, the source of the crash from the Suggestions Bar is apparently the form of the array output for `l2`. A smaller (non-)working example that I found is `{{{1, 2}, 0}, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, 0}}`. Given that just having these kinds of nested sub-lists can cause kernel crashes is probably a great reason to turn the Suggestions Bar off and leave it off.